# Windows sorting order in JAVA and python

Tags: java, python, windows, sorting, compare

I have below files in my Windows XP. which After sorting according to name orders in below manner.

```
test_1a.play
test_1AA.play
test_1aaa.play
test_1AB.play
test_1AC.play
test-_1AAAA.play
```

If I read these files in java and do Collections.sort(listofFiles) 
or python and do listofFiles.sort()
I get below order

```
test-_1AAAA.play
test_1AA.play
test_1AB.play
test_1AC.play
test_1a.play
test_1aaa.play
```

In GUI I need to display the files in the order which windows is ordering. Folders with above names are sorted by default sorting mechanism. only files are disordered. 
So I am searching for a compare method which is used in windows to use for java and python. **Can any one help me with comparator to solve this**

Answer (score 1):

Try that :

```
    Collections.sort(files,new Comparator<File>()
    {
        Collator myCollator = Collator.getInstance();
        @Override
        public int compare(File o1, File o2)
        {
            return myCollator.compare(o1.getName(),o2.getName());
        }
    });
```

The difference was because Windows is case insensitive. If you look at the doc of the [Collator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html) it says :

> The Collator class performs locale-sensitive String comparison.

You just have to do a comparator with that. If your List is not a list of files but a list of strings it is even easier since the compartor already exists : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER

Comment: thanks for reply. Windows is handing special character which is making lot of difference. So even comparing with case-insensitive is not helping :(